# Switched from Zend Debugger to XDebug -Zend Server giving me an UserServer Error

Tags: xdebug, zend-debugger, zend-server-ce

I switched from Zend Debugger to XDebug, while I got XDebug to work fine, my zend server isn't starting up right. I get the following error message in the browser window:

```
UserServer Error: Call to non-existing function: zend_is_configuration_changed() in ZwasComponents_Util_Api_UserServer::isConfigurationChanged()
```

I'm quite sure this has something to do with me disabling Zend Debugger and installing XDebug - but how do I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xdebug is incompatible with the Zend Optimizer and Zend Studio Debugger extensions. These extensions should be commented out.

see: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug